# Ola's maintenance solution is not processing sysjob* tables

Tags: sql-server, maintenance, ola-hallengren, system-tables, index-maintenance

I have used [Ola Hallengren's script](https://ola.hallengren.com/) to back up and maintain databases.

However, it does not perform any reindex or reorganize operations against certain tables in `msdb`, such as `sysjobhistory`, even though they have fragmentation above the defined thresholds. Here is the script I am using:

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
  @Databases = 'SYSTEM_DATABASES',
  @FragmentationLow = NULL,
  @FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
  @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
  @FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
  @FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
  @UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
  @OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 7):

You need an additional parameter to tell Ola's script to consider Microsoft-shipped objects, since those job-related tables in `msdb` are marked as `is_ms_shipped`:

```
@MSShippedObjects = N'Y'
```

(This parameter defaults to N'N', which means *ignore* Microsoft-shipped objects, and is documented [here](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html).)

Comment: Is it recommended to use this for Microsoft-shipped objects? Or is there anything to think about before?

Comment: @Mcol I don't know of any problems - Microsoft ships very few *tables* these days that a user could do anything to - but to be safe I would probably restrict this to the database most likely to have those (and where fragmentation might even be a problem), which is `msdb` rather than all system databases. I don't think I would run defrag at all against `master`, `tempdb`, or even `model` (unless you develop user data there).